# Extraindo dados postgreSQL para arquivo

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou tentando extrair os dados de uma tabela para um arquivo com o seguinte comando:

```
COPY historico TO '/home/jessica/teste.txt';
```

Mas o seguinte erro ocorre:

> ERROR:  could not open file "/home/jessica/teste.txt" for writing:
>   Permissão negada

Comment: qual sistema operacional? esta fazendo isso direto no código? que linguagem? ou esta tentando pelo pgAdmin?

Comment: Uso ubuntu. Estou fazendo pelo terminal, logada no banco de dados dentro do postgresql mesmo.

Comment: Creio que o usuário "postgres", não possui permissão para criar arquivos dentro da pasta do usuário "jessica", logue com o usuario "jessica" e de um `chmod -R 0777` na pasta `/home/jessica`, apos tento o processo novamente

Comment: Jessica **não use o `chmod -R 0777`** sugerido pelo guilherme lautert,  `777 -R` é "libera TUDO para TODO mundo nessa pasta, nas subpastas e nos arquivos contidos" e você raramente quer fazer algo assim no seu sistema.

Answer (score 1):

O usuário que você está acessando o banco não tem permissão para criar o arquivo no diretorio /home/jessica/

Você pode fazer o seguinte comando:

```
COPY historico TO '/tmp/teste.txt';
```

No diretorio /tmp todos os usuário do sistema podem acessar ele normalmente e de lá, você manipula o seu arquivo.

Espero ter ajudado.